# FFmpeg: chromakey without green edges

Tags: ffmpeg, chromakey

I have a video of a person on green background and I'm trying to turn background transparent:

```bash
ffmpeg -i bg.mp4 -i man.mp4 -filter_complex '[1:v]colorkey=0x00ff00:0.3:0.3[ckout];[0:v][ckout]overlay[out]' -map '[out]' result.mp4
```

Colorkey gives this quite noticeable green edge around the person's figure.
Any attempts to increase opacity or blend parameters result in disappearing facial features.

[image]

Is there any smart way to change pure green `0x00ff00` pixels with transparent ones?

Answer (score 0):

To me it is just the matter of the edge color

The [colorkey](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#colorkey) has a similarity parameter; should you try not using 1

Since i don't have any asset to try on this parameter, good luck.